# send integers via python socket module

Tags: python, sockets, module, integer, signed

I am trying to send signed integers from python to a PCB. I want to send the number 01 via python, but my PCB keeps interpreting it as "12592" when I write that in binary, that is: 00110000 00110001"

each byte is 48 and 49 - those are the ascii values for 0 and 1 - so the format is what is wrong - I litteraly want to send 10000000 and 10000001 instead, such the PCB interprets it correctly

my code is pretty simple at the moment - i am "send" funciton from the python socket module, and writing socket.send(b'01') - however, i cannot find any other functions in the socket module to do this? is there some way to ask it to send it as signed int instead?

Comment: You are sending a binary *string* "01", so UTF-8 char "0" and then UTF-8 char "1"

Comment: Maybe you should use something as `bytes([0,1])` instead of `b'01'` ?

Comment: @LaurentH.   `bytes([0,1])` and `b'01'` are the same...

Comment: @D.L Not at all. Please look at the answer from mdurant.

Comment: @LaurentH.   thanks for pointing that out.  i have upvoted your comment.

Answer (score 0):

@Laurent H. in the comments above, is exactly right. You want to send binary values, not the binary equivalent of ascii codes for number characters.

```
 bytes([0,1]) == b'\x00\x01'
```

which is *not* what you were sending.

Conversely,

```
ord("0") == 48
```

Is the numerical value that gets you the character for zero.

Actually, you could even send binary directly, here with your signs applied:

```
0b10000000, 0b10000001 == (128, 129)
b'\x80\x81'  # as byte values
```

Answer (score 0):

If you sent `b'01'` that sends the literal ASCII byte values 0x30, 0x31. `12592 == 0x3130` which is the little-endian binary interpretation of those bytes.

Use the [`struct.pack('<h', n)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) function to pack the integer `n` as a little-endian signed 16-bit integer.

Examples:

```py
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('<h', 1)
b'\x01\x00'
>>> struct.pack('<h', 0x1213)
b'\x13\x12'
```